# Get orders for a particular year using CASE WHEN

Tags: sql, left-join, case-when

I'm using this [order dataset](http://qa.geeksforgeeks.org/4150/write-sql-queries-important-practice-questions) and trying to get 2 columns of data, one of 1998 orders and one of 1996 orders alongside each seller's name.

My SQL so far is:

```
select
    salesperson.name,
    case when strftime('%Y', order_date) = 1998 then sum(orders.number) end as sales_in_1998,
    case when strftime('%Y', order_date) = 1996 then sum(orders.number) end as sales_in_1996
from salesperson
left join orders on orders.salesperson_id = salesperson.id
group by salesperson.name;
```

(sorry no `YEAR()` function since I loaded it into sqlite)

However, I'm just getting NULLs for everything. What am I doing wrong?

[Here is my SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/a93301/1) with the data loaded in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The `CASE` goes inside the `SUM()`.
2. Use single quotes for string comparisons.

The resulting query:

```
select sp.name,
       sum(case when strftime('%Y', o.order_date) = '1998' then o.number 
           end) as sales_in_1998,
       sum(case when strftime('%Y', o.order_date) = '1996' then o.number 
           end) as sales_in_1996
from salesperson sp left join
     orders o
     on o.salesperson_id = sp.id
group by sp.name;
```

Comment: Nice! Thanks. I forgot that STRFTIME returns strings. Also, I added an ELSE 0 to the end of the CASE WHENs to neaten up the resultset :)